# Copied NSMutableDictionary not mutable

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

need to make a copy of a NSMutableDictionary by:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newScoutingEventDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.scoutingEvent copyItems:YES] mutableCopy];
```

but when i try to mutate an array in it:

```
[[newScoutingEventDictionary objectForKey:@"myArray"] replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:appendedEntry];
```

it gives me an error:

```
 -[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x964d650
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x964d650'
```

if i try to mutate the original NSMutableDictionary:

```
[[self.scoutingEvent objectForKey:@"myArray"] replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:appendedEntry];
```

it runs just fine. why is my copied version breaking it?

Comment: I should point out that `NSMutableDictionary *newScoutingEventDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.scoutingEvent copyItems:YES] mutableCopy];` in fact makes two copies, the first of which is leaked…

Comment: er.... how so? i don't see/understand it.

Comment: To be precise, it creates two new instances, from the [basic memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), "alloc" means one instance gets created, and "mutableCopy" a second one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mutableCopy` does a *shallow* mutable copy.  It isn't going to make immutable objects within the dictionary mutable.

You need to implement -- yes, implement as it is not a part of the API for a variety of reasons -- deep mutable copying, if that is what you need.

Alternatively, if your dictionary can be represented as a property list, you can turn into one and then use the various options parameters to make mutable collections and/or leaves when it is unarchived.

Comment: i played around with it, i removed the mutableCopy and set copyItem to no (basically just use the initWithDiciontary: method). i now have a copy of the original dictionary. i can alter the copy (replaceObjectAtIndex:) and the original does not change. :?